# Cannot enter data from keyboard in R

Tags: r, xcode

I think I have some issue with my XCode package, because I cannot enter data via the built-in editor on R. I can open the editor with:

```
mydata <- data.frame(age=numeric(0), gender=character(0), weight=numeric(0))

mydata <- edit(mydata)
```

And change the names of the columns, but not add any data. When I close the editor, I get the following:

```
Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_de.so'' had status 69
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get around to accepting `xcode`'s terms and conditions? Run `sudo xcodebuild --license` from the command line to get that done or just open the `xcode` IDE and accept the terms and conditions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to accept xcode's terms adn conditions. Thanks Abdou!